# Understanding Hatcher exercise 1.1.13

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Given a space $X$ and a path-connected subspace $A$ containing the basepoint $x_0$, show that the map $π_1(A, x_0) \to π_1(X, x_0)$ induced by the inclusion $A \hookrightarrow X$ is surjective iff every path in $X$ with endpoints in $A$ is homotopic to a path in $A$.

I'm wondering the proof of reverse direction. Most of the proof says that as every path in $X$ with endpoints in $A$ is homotopic to a path in $A$, if we choose a loop in $X$ based at $x_0$, then is homotopic to $\textbf{a loop in $A$ based at $x_0$}$. I don't understand this. Hypothesis only assume it's homotopic to some path in $A$ so I think the homotopic path need not be a loop. Am I right or I'm misunderstanding something here? In this case how can I prove?

Comment: Maybe "homotopic" means _path homotopic_.

Comment: @azif00 Ok then it's clear. But if we just assume two paths are homotopic not necessary path homotopic, then the statement is false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of fundamental groups "homotopic" always means "path homotopic", i.e. homotopies are required to keep the endpoints of the paths fixed.

Understanding it in the sense of *arbitrary homotopies* does not make because **any two paths** in the same path component of $X$ are homotopic.